# Create parent child object simultaneously when both has no validation/uniqueness issue using encode/databases wrapper

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi, starlette

I have a following model where a parent can have many children. User can just create the parent
or create a parent along with the child at the same time.

```
class Parent(Base):
  name = Column(String)
  slug = Column(String)
  values = relationship('Child', back_populates='parent')

class Child(Base):
  name = Column(String, unique=True)
  slug = Column(String)
  parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
  parent = relationship('Parent', back_populates='values')
```

I need to create a parent but if values is send then create a child as well. The problem here
is to create a Child, parent id is needed. If I create a parent and then get the id and while
creating a child if there is any error like name uniquess for same parent id then there will be broken parent object. How can I create
both parent and child once there is no issue in both table?

I am using encode/database for async database operation so I have no idea of doing such

```
parent = Parent(name='Parent name')
child = Child(name='Child name', slug='child-name')
session.add_all([parent, child])
session.commit()
```

when using encode database library https://github.com/encode/databases
This is what I am trying

```
async def check_values_are_unique(db, child_value, parent):
    # get the list of slugs of particular attribute.
    # alternative of django values_list in sqlalchemy
    existing_values = await db.execute(select(parent.values.slug).distinct()).all()
    # some check is done here like Value already exists within this parent


async def create_parent(db, data):
  # data -> Parent(name='Parent name', values=[Child(name='Child name', value='child name')])
  values_input = data.values
  parent_qs = Parent.__table__.select().where(
        Parent.__table__.c.name == data.name
    )
  parent_exists = await db.fetch_one(query=parent_qs)
  if parent_exists:
      return Error(
          code="PARENT_ALREADY_EXIST",
          message=f"Parent with name {data.name} already exist",
      )
  else:
      # create an instance of attribute
      parent_input = data.__dict__
      del parent_input["values"]
      # create an instance 
      parent = Parent.__table__.insert().values(**parent_input)
      for val in values_input:
          setattr(val, "slug", slugify(val.name))
          child_value = Child.__table__.insert().values(
              **val.__dict__, parent=parent
          )
      check_values_are_unique(db, values_input, parent)
```

UPDATED CODE

```
async def create_parent(db, data):
  # data -> Parent(name='Parent name', values=[Child(name='Child name', value='child name')])
  values_input = data.values
  parent_qs = Parent.__table__.select().where(
        Parent.__table__.c.name == data.name
    )
  parent_exists = await db.fetch_one(query=parent_qs)
  if parent_exists:
      return Error(
          code="PARENT_ALREADY_EXIST",
          message=f"Parent with name {data.name} already exist",
      )
  else:
      # create an instance of attribute
      parent_input = data.__dict__
      del parent_input["values"]
      # create an instance 
      parent = Parent.__table__.insert().values(**parent_input)
      for val in values_input:
          setattr(val, "slug", slugify(val.name))
          child_value = Child.__table__.insert().values(
              **val.__dict__, parent=parent
          )
      async with db.transaction():
            # this will create a parent instance but wont get save to database
            parent = Parent(**parent_input)
            for val in values_input:
                setattr(val, "slug", slugify(val.name))
                child_value = Child(**val.__dict__, parent=parent)
                # child.values.append(child_value)
            print('now save')
            # NOW SAVE PARENT AND CHILD IN DB
            print("parent", parent.__dict__) # it has values as well
            # parent {'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7f51abda5430>, 'name': 'parent name', 'slug': 'parent-name', 'values': [<app.models.parent.parent.Child object at 0x7f51abda5520>, <app.models.parent.parent.Child object at 0x7f51abda5520>]}
            parent_id = await db.execute(
                Parent.__table__.insert().values(
                    name=parent.name,
                    slug=parent.slug
                )
            )
            print("parent_id", parent_id)
            response_payload = {
                **data.__dict__,
                "id": parent_id,
                "choices": values_input, # no idea to get list of values with id 
            }
            print("response payload", response_payload)

            return ParentPayload(**response_payload)
```

I could save Parent object but not child and you can see in the comment for `print ('parent', parent.__dict__)`. It has list of values as well.

Comment: You can first create the parent, retrieve the id of the parent and use it to create the child. All of it within a transaction https://www.encode.io/databases/connections_and_transactions/#transactions

Comment: @lsabi Thank you for your comment. I could not understand how to use from that documentation. If its okay to you, can you put sample code in your answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the setup to test it right now, but this should give you a guideline of how it should be done.

Here, the `database` object is the connected instance of the database. The operations that are performed within this context will be part of the same transaction.

```
else:
      # create an instance of attribute
      parent_input = data.__dict__
      del parent_input["values"]
      async with database.transaction():
          # create parent instance 
          parent = Parent.__table__.insert().values(**parent_input)
          for val in values_input:
              setattr(val, "slug", slugify(val.name))
              child_value = Child.__table__.insert().values(
                  **val.__dict__, parent=parent
              )
      check_values_are_unique(db, values_input, parent)
```

Comment: I am getting `"message": "SQL expression element expected, got <sqlalchemy.sql.dml.Insert object at 0x7f0e01e1fe20>.",` issue on line `child_value = Child.__table__.insert().values(
                  **val.__dict__, parent=parent
              )`.

Comment: Does your code work? This error means that your code is expecting a SQL expression, not an object. Probably it is due to parent=parent. Maybe using parent_id=parent.id or something else should help

Comment: if I do parent = Parent(**parent_input) rather then it works.

Comment: Does it insert the parent in the database?

Comment: I am getting issue on other line `existing_values = await db.execute(select(parent.values.slug).distinct()).all()` to get the list/tuple of slugs. Once I fix this I will try inserting and will let you know.

Comment: ```parent_id = await db.execute(
                Parent.__table__.insert().values(
                    name=parent.name,
                    slug=parent.slug
                )
            )
``` creates a parent object but not child. If I pass values = parent.values then I get 'unused column values'.

Comment: You cannot create both parent and child at once. You have to first create the parent and then the child. This will help you understand better why https://www.ahmed-ibrahim.com/relational-database-transaction-acid-in-dbms/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will read it carefully. Before reading the article you suggested, I will make an assumption that I will have to do something like ```parent_id = await db.execute(Parent.__table__.insert().values(name=parent.name, slug=parent.slug))``` and then ```child = await db.exeucte(Child.__table__.insert().values(name=child.name, slug=child.slug, parent=parent_id))```. Am I right?

Comment: If its the way then I think if you put those things in the answer then I should mark it as answered.

Comment: Yes, it is what I meant. Does it work as expected on your code?

Comment: Parent got created in the database but I am sorry I am so confused on creating child object as it will have multiple values. I have updated my code. Can you once look at it, please? Also can you look at parent.__dict__ where there is list of values that belongs to child.

Comment: You just copied and pasted my code....As I said, it needs to be checked since I haven't worked with that particular library. Though, the error is quite simple: you need to insert the parent and child creation in a transaction. You'll first create the parent and then add the children using the parent's reference